# How to display a matplotlib figure created directly from Figure class?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How to display figures that were not created using pyplot/pylab figure(), but constructed directly from matplotlib's Figure class?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
figure = mpl.figure.Figure()
figure.show() # this won't work
```

Answer (score 2):

### Direct Figure / Tkinter co-integration

Sample code ( Class-based demo ) is posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25769600/3666197

Principle works via a

```
class SuperShapeFrame( Frame ):                                         # The user interface:
```

where both an MVC-Controller UI-interactions and an MVC-Model outputs are re-processed and the resulting output state of a <kbd>Figure</kbd> object is sent to MVC-Visual part ( handled by a <kbd>FigureCanvasTkAgg</kbd> object, `.grid()`-mounted into Tkinter )

```
self.fig        = Figure( ( 6, 6 ), dpi = 100 )                         # matplotlib side
canvas          = FigureCanvasTkAgg( self.fig, master = self )          # canvas
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid( row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4 )      # grid()-ed into Tkinter
```

For the full source, use the link above

Answer (score 1):

Figures that were not created using pyplot/pylab figure() but constructed directly from matplotlib's Figure class need a figure manager:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg

figure = mpl.figure.Figure()

window = Tk.Tk()
canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window)
figManager = tkagg.FigureManagerTkAgg(canvas, 0, window)
figManager.show()
```

This might also be doable using `backend_tkagg.new_figure_manager_given_figure()` function, but that function does not yet exist in my version of `python-matplotlib` (1.1.1~rc1+git20120423-0ubuntu1).

Comment: Sadly, that function actually still depends on pyplot.  I would suggest you upgrade your mpl, we are now on v1.4.0