# Drawing a diagram using sliders from Tkinter - Program has no output

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, draw

I want to make a program that draws a diagram of [Lennard-Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) with parameters epsilon and sigma being adjustable with two sliders. I want my program to work like this

1. Small window with two sliders appear
2. I adjust both sliders
3. I click "show"
4. A diagram of potential appears

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

import pylab as p

def show_values():
    V=4*epsilon.get()*(math.pow((sigma.get()/r),12)-math.pow((sigma.get()/r,6)))
    p.plot(t,V)
    p.show()


r = p.arange(0.1, 5.0, 0.01)
master = Tk()
epsilon = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42)
epsilon.pack()
sigma = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sigma.pack()



Button(master, text='Show', command=show_values).pack()
master.mainloop()
```

When I click "run the current file" nothing happens. No error messages. Whad I did wrong? I work in canopy 32-bit, windows 7.

Comment: May be interested in a fully Tkinter-integrated plotting >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/25976648/3666197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have constructed your window, you need to call the `mainloop()` method to show it. Adding `master.mainloop()` after the last line does the trick.

Comment: I added master.mainloop() after the last line and still nothing happens. 
I edited my question, so the code includes your suggestion.
:-)

Comment: Oh! Excuse me! It's just my laptop working slowly. Something happened: window with sliders appeared. But now, when I click "show"... nothing happens.

Comment: O.... and now I noticed some errors in the rest of the code: 
p.plot(t,V) should be replaced with p.plot(r,V). And there were some problems with math.pow, so I replaced it with **