# Matplotlib and python garbage collection in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-management, garbage-collection

I need to export multiple plots with Python and Matplotlib but I have issues with the memory management.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook in Windows and the code is structured as shown in the working example here below. Basically, I'm generating a daily plot over a period of several years.

Following the memory usage I can see that usually for the first 4 "months" the memory usage is fairly stable but then it increases more than 15MB for each "day". With the complete code this leads to a memory error.

I tried to use `plt.close()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845116/numpy-and-matplotlib-garbage-collection). I also tried `plt.close(fig)`, `plt.close('all')` and to manually delete some variables with `del`. Finally I've put `gc.collect` in the loop. Nothing seems to have any effect.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gc

sz = 1000
i=0
for year in [2014,2015,2016,2017]:
    for month in [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12]:
        for day in range(1,30):

            # Plot
            fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(14,10))

            x1 = np.arange(1,sz+1,1)
            y1 = np.random.random(sz)
            ax1.scatter(x1,y1)
            ax2.scatter(x1,y1)
            ax3.scatter(x1,y1)
            ax4.scatter(x1,y1)

            filename = 'test/test_output{}{}{}.png'.format(year,month,day)
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')

            #plt.close(fig)            
            #plt.close('all')
            plt.close()

            del x1, y1, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, fig

            # counter
            i=i+1

        # Monthly operations
        print(filename,i)
        gc.collect()

# Triggered outside the loops
gc.collect()
```

On the other hand, if I interrupt the code (or I wait for the "Memory error" to occur) and then I run manually `gc.collect`, the memory is cleaned right away.

Why `gc.collect` does not have any effect in the nested loops?

Is there a way to improve the memory management for this code?

Comment: What happens if you run as a script instead of in a notebook?   I can imagine her notebook doing funky things when given hundreds of plots even if you close them.

Comment: I tried to run the script with Spyder and it happens the same (Python 3.6.4 - Spyder 3.2.6 - IPython 6.2.1).

Comment: "As script" means *outside* of IPython or similar, i.e. in the console run `python scipt_name.py`. How do you measure memory usage?

Comment: Ok, I tried to run the code as a script and the memory usage is kept correcly under control. It seems that `plt.close()` works as expected in this case. So the problem is with IPython and I still cannot find a solution. For checking the memory usage here I simply watch the Task Manager.

Comment: What happens if you turn interactive mode off, `plt.ioff()` when in IPython?